# I get "404 not found" with proxy Vite + Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vite

I have a problem with proxy Vite + Vue.js. In [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost), it is working perfectly, but when deploying it on a server, it always gets the "error 404 not found".

I tried every solution on the web, but it is still not working. What is the solution?

Comment: This depends on your web server config, which is unknown.